# Can the Rpi2 or Rpi3 download files for a LINUX OS to flash drive?

Tags: raspbian, usb

I want to put the Raspbian OS on my PC. The PC doesn't have any OS on it now. The only access to the internet I have is by Android or Raspberry Pi. So is it possible to get a Linux distro or Raspbian onto a Flash drive  using Rpi2 or Rpi3? I don't care if it cannot be installed on the PC as long as it will run of the USB Flash Drive.

Comment: Yes, why would you think this is not possible (the Pi is a full Linux system)? You just need to create a bootable flashdrive.

Comment: I did but the folders on the USB are empty.

Comment: Then you need to explain what you did in your question. You should also search how to create a bootable flash drive image using Linux.

Comment: Ok I will research that. I didn't explain because it was a few weeks ago I tried I didn't document anything. I just thought I would ask if it was possible before trying again. I will document this try. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pixel-pc-mac/) is what you are looking for. This is an x86 version of Raspbian made specifically to run on Macs and PCs. The Raspbian you have on your Pi is built for ARM processors. If you have enough storage space on the Pi, you can download this using the Pi and make a bootable USB flash drive for the PC.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks for reminding me I that the pi uses ARM processors. It will help me way more than my question.  Much appreciated!